# Temp Table with WHERE Concat LIKE

Tags: sql-server, sql-like, temp-tables

I have a table I want to keep open to sort multiple ways on the fly, so I am inserting into a temp table, but when I try to CONCAT the WHERE statement it can take up to 5 minutes for less then 5k rows ... how would I do a CONCAT to find a string in a CONCAT string and not take forever... if i do a basic select i can return stuff within a few seconds

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTest') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #TempTest

SELECT TOP 1000 * 
INTO #TempTest 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         hcp_urls_id, 
         CONCAT (hcp_protocol_text, hcp_protocol_split, hcp_domains_text, hcp_paths_text, '?', hcp_querystrings_text) AS hcp_urls_concat,
         hcp_urls_page_statuscode
     FROM 
         hcp_urls 
     INNER JOIN 
         hcp_paths ON hcp_paths_id = hcp_urls_paths_id 
     INNER JOIN 
         hcp_domains ON hcp_domains_id = hcp_urls_domains_id 
     INNER JOIN 
         hcp_protocol ON hcp_protocol_id = hcp_urls_protocol_id 
     FULL OUTER JOIN 
         hcp_querystrings ON hcp_querystrings_id = hcp_urls_querystrings_id
     WHERE   
         CONCAT (hhcp_protocol_text, hcp_protocol_split, hcp_domains_text,hcp_paths_text, '?', hcp_querystrings_text) LIKE '%www.test.com/url%') AS tmpTest
```

Comment: `Where concat(...)` is most definitely not sargable and is no surprise it performs badly - SQL Server must join your tables, scan *every* row, read every row into ram, concatenate the text from all the columns and then perform the `like` filter clause; it would be better to address each colum separately, especially if the searched for text is at the start of each column. Sample data, table schema, indexes, constraints and the actual execution plan via [PasteThePlan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan) would help further.

Comment: is there a way around this, i mean the table i am pulling from has 100k rows and I want to filter based on that... is there a way to do the like on the same concat i am doing in the select part?

Comment: Separate note, using a `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` means that the rows you do get will be arbitrary and could be different every time you run the query. If you want consistent results, add an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @Larnu.. yes I was hoping to put this into a temp-table to sort the results a few times for different exports instead of running the stress query 5 times

Comment: Why `CONCAT` though, just use `OR` like this: `hhcp_protocol_text LIKE '%www.test.com/url%' OR hcp_protocol_split LIKE '%www.test.com/url%'....` alternatively if you need to check each part separately then do so `hhcp_protocol_text = 'https' AND hcp_domains_text = 'www.test.com/url%'....`

Comment: @Charlieface cause each of the concats create a string, and the search could be across any of the concatted parts ... so the concat creates a url string with a possible querystring etc, and someone might query the domain and path or just the domain or part of the querystring, i dont know what part they are querying

Comment: Is there no way you can split the search string into its constituent parts and search each individually?

Comment: @Charlieface that is what i was trying but it seems to take just as long cause I have to validate every section and then revalidate the previous part is a parent of the next part...

and technically i have no idea what they searching cause they could say "example.com" is their search term and that could be in the querystring or the domain or path parts..

Comment: Then an Indexed View of the concatenated expression might be a good way forward, but you can't use `FULL JOIN`, can that be avoided or perhaps can we search that table separately?

Comment: I have bit the bullet and decided to create a table with the full string in a single column .. so whenever the divided areas get added to their respectful tables, i concat the full string and put into another table for indexing and reference the parent table with the id.